# Unix script , declare array

Tags: arrays, bash, unix

I try to declare an array and access its contents like this

```
declare -a VAR
VAR[0]=text1
VAR[1]=text2
VAR[2]=text3
echo $VAR[1]
```

But it doesn't work.
Can you fix my code and also tell me why we don't have to declare the size
of an array in UNIX when we declare it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
declare -a VAR
VAR[0]=text1
VAR[1]=text2
VAR[2]=text3
echo ${VAR[1]}
```

> Any element of an array may be referenced using ${name[subscript]}.

[more info](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Arrays.html)